# Stuck at the derivation of divergence in Cartesian coordinates.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'll get to the point immediately. The definition of divergence in a point (from my textbook): 
$$ div \bar{E} = \lim_{V \to 0} \frac{1}{V}\oint_S \bar{E}.d\bar{S}$$  (it's a surface integral)

[Context (contains a figure)](https://slimgur.com/images/2015/08/21/3381c8a67bd54795b5f1b84a756be53b.png): to show what divergence looks like in Cartesian coordinates for the vector field E, we will work with an infinitesimal volume with dimensions  ∆$x$ x  ∆$y$ x  ∆$z$. (A cuboid or w/e) We  will shrink this volume to a point ($x,y,z$). The surface integral is spread over the 6 surfaces Ⅰ,..., Ⅵ. 'Ⅰ' means the integral over the Ⅰ-side. The next part is where the problems begin.

Lets focus on sides   Ⅰ and Ⅱ. (Left and right on the drawing). For a limit where ∆x, ∆y and ∆z approach 0, the integral over 'Ⅰ' approaches E<sub>$x$</sub>($x$+∆$x$,$y$,$z$)∆$y$∆$z$ and the integral over 'Ⅱ' approaches - E<sub>$x$</sub>($x$,$y$,$z$)∆$y$∆$z$.

That's what I don't understand. How do you get there? I assume it is by applying the definition. If anyone can help me understand that part, that would be awesome. The goals is that, when you apply the same logic to all sides, you get the expression: $$ div \bar{E} = \frac{\partial E_{x}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial E_{y}}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial E_{z}}{\partial z}$$

I'm confident that once I understand that, I'll be able to figure out the rest. The 'div E<sub>Ⅰ+Ⅱ</sub> = ...' part is just applying the formal definition of a derivative.

Comment: When $\Delta y, \Delta z$ are sufficiently small, $E_x$ varies little over the face and can be approximated by a constant. So the integral is approximately that constant value times the area.

Comment: @PaulSinclair
That constant would then be the $E_{x}(x+\Delta x,y,z)$?

Comment: The constant would be the value of $E_x$ at a useful point on the surface in question. For side I, $(x+\Delta x,y,z)$ lies on it. For II, $(x,y,z)$ lies on it.

Comment: I think I understand it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rigorous way would be to Taylor expand $E$ on each of the faces. Example for faces I and II:

$$\int_I E(x', y', z') \cdot dS' = E_x (x, y, z) \, \Delta y \, \Delta z + \partial_x E_x |_{x,y,z} \Delta x \, \Delta y \, \Delta z + \text{higher order terms}$$

and

$$\int_{II} E(x', y', z') \cdot dS' = -E_x (x, y, z) \, \Delta y \, \Delta z + \text{higher order terms}$$

When you add these contributions together, the terms proportional to $\Delta y \Delta z$ exactly cancel, the terms proportional to $\Delta x \, \Delta y \, \Delta z$ contribute terms of $O(1)$ to the limit you need to take, and everything of higher order goes to zero in the limit. (Exercise: compute some of these higher order terms to convince yourself this is the case.)

Repeat this process for the other faces, and you're done.

Comment: I have no idea how you got to your Taylor expansion. Here's my attempt. 


Taylor expansion: $$ f(x',y',z')   = f(x,y,z) + (x'-x)f_{x'}(x,y,z) + (y'-y)f_{y'}(x,y,z) + (z'-z)f_{z'}(x,y,z) + ...$$

For the first term, I assume that we put (x,y,z) in E(x',y',z') which gives us E(x,y,z), a constant c. The first term would then be: $$\int cdS = cS = c\Delta y \Delta z = E(x,y,z)\Delta y \Delta z$$

The second term. I assume the $\partial_x E = E_x$ from OP? $\Delta y, \Delta z$ come from S. $\Delta x$ should come from (x'-x), right? 

It feels like I got it after writing it out like this.

Comment: Yes, though I will have to correct it all to use $E_x$, as the surface integrals should result in scalars.

Comment: I'm still stuck. The first term works fine, but the second one is still problematic. How am I supposed to take $\frac{\partial \int E(x',y',z')}{\partial x}$? I don't see how I can get $\Delta y$ and $\Delta z$ out of it. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: You should Taylor expand first and then integrate.

Comment: So like this?

$$E(x',y',z') = E(x,y,z) + (x'-x)\partial_x E |_{x,y,z} + ... $$

$$\int E(x',y',z') dS = \int E(x,y,z) dS + \int E_x(x,y,z) \Delta x dS +.... $$

And both $E(x,y,z)$ and $E_x (x,y,z) \Delta x$ are constants, which makes integrating easier, and gives us $\Delta y$ and $\Delta z$.

Comment: Yes, but you should take care not to use the same notation for partial derivatives as for vector components.

Comment: It still won't work. In your first post, you said that the terms proportional to $\Delta y \Delta z$ should cancel. According to my textbook (see context link), that's not the case. Those terms are used later in the definition of the derivative. The terms proportional to $\Delta x \Delta y \Delta z$, do seem to cancel.

When I try it myself. I get: $$ E(x+\Delta x,y,z)\Delta y \Delta z + E(x,y,z)\Delta y \Delta z$$ (for the first terms)

I also fail to see how you get the '-' for $\int _{II}$. 

I'm either doing something horribly wrong, or I don't understand it at all, perhaps both.

Comment: I expand the series in terms of all three coordinates; the book only does so on the coordinates that vary on each surface. The approaches are equivalent; expand the $E(x+\Delta x, y, z)$ term as a series in $x$ and the derivative appears, without needing to use the limit definition. - The signs of the terms depend on the orientation of the integration surface. Surfaces I and II must be oppositely oriented.